# Is it possible to sort an XML file using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

hello friends i had developed one project in .net 
first thing is that i create one request xml file in that all the data is there ... after that i got one response xml file from web . now i need to sort this xml file on the basis of requested input file ...

```
ex: itaniary=bom -del = flight=AI Arrivaltime=10.20
```

now i need to sort this xml file using xsl 
so which code is added in

Comment: Sorry, but your English is simply too broken to salvage this post. There is now way to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: "aal yhe daat" => "all the data"?  Cmon, frnd: taking the time to eliminate typos from your question will significantly increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Remember that XSLT and English are both case-sensitive languages.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to sort an XML file
>   using XSL?

Yes. In more than one way.

**When talking about sorting one needs to specify**:

1. Which exactly nodes need to be rearranged (sorted).
2. what are the sorting keys - the expression over each node that when calculated gives its "value" to be used in the sorting operation.
3. The comparator function -- in XSLT this is part of the expression, but may be omitted if the type of the sort keys allows the default `lt` operation.
4. The order (ascending or descending) in which to present the result of the sort.

**Read about the [`<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#sorting) and the [`<xsl:perform-sort>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-perform-sort) instructions** (the latter available only in XSLT 2.0).

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the title only, I would say [the answer is "yes"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`XSLT <xsl:sort>` Element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_sort.asp).